# Rotate a image in c++

Tags: visual-c++

Hi I am very new to c++.

```
Image im(L"C:\\Temp\\SnapShotOutput.jpg");
im.RotateFlip(Rotate90FlipNone);
im.Save("SampleImage_rotated.jpg");
```

I am trying to above code to rotate a image and save...
It wont work .compile fail at the 3rd line

```
'Gdiplus::Image::Save' : no overloaded function takes 1 arguments
```

it gives the above error.
can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should set other parameters too. Code is from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
Image image(L"C:\\Temp\\SnapShotOutput.jpg");
image.RotateFlip(Rotate90FlipNone);

// Save the altered image as PNG
CLSID pngClsid;
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
image.Save(L"SampleImage_rotated.png", &pngClsid, NULL);

// Save the altered image as JPG
CLSID jpegClsid;
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &jpegClsid);
image.Save(L"SampleImage_rotated.jpg", &jpegClsid, NULL);
```

The **GetEncoderClsid** function is defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
   UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
   UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

   ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

   GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
   if(size == 0)
      return -1;  // Failure

   pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
   if(pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
      return -1;  // Failure

   GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

   for(UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
   {
      if( wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0 )
      {
         *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
         free(pImageCodecInfo);
         return j;  // Success
      }    
   }

   free(pImageCodecInfo);
   return -1;  // Failure
}
```